# add if does not already exist

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-viewsets

Hello every one I'm trying to write a View Set API, that let you add course obj to your favorite list,but before adding  check it if user added course already don't let user add again and if user didn't add so let user add it to the list,
but I don't have any idea how can I do it with View set
my view

```
class AddtoMyCoursesView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyCoursesListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = self.request.POST.get('pk')
        course = get_object_or_404(Courses, id=pk)
        print(course)
        course_list, _ = MyCoursesList.objects.filter(courses=course).exist()
        print(course_list)
        course_list.courses.add(course_list)
```

My model is

```
class MyCoursesList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    courses = models.ForeignKey(Courses, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,related_name='my_courses')
    added_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default=1)
```

So what should I do to my code??

Answer (score 0):

Use [Modelname.get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) for this purpose.

Comment: I wrote like this before it dosen’t work

Comment: Can you share that code? And also what possible issue it was having. As I had a similar implementation in my one of my projects.